# Using hashcat -s with --increment

Tags: hashcat

I have multiple computers which I am planning to use. They all run a custom-made client that starts hashcat with different args.

I am able to submit the current progress, candidates etc (everything in console output) to the server, but I am unsure how I would format the arguments for the client.

Example:

- PC 1 starts and quits after 100 hashes generated.
- Now PC 2 starts and receives the exact same start command, leading to the same hashes being checked again (or does it?).
- I would like to tell PC 2 "Hey, 100 passwords were already tested, skip those and start from 101!".

After some googling I found that I could use `-s` to do that. But is the order the passwords I am generating always the same or does it differ? My start command is (roughly):

```
hashcat.exe -m 17400  -o outfile.txt --session charsession -a 3 --increment --increment-min 8 [b]-s 12345[/b] wallethash.txt ?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a
```

But I just saw it's not possible with `--increment`, so what should I do now? Wordlists are not an option due to me having to go through 8 and 9 char strings.

So, to sum it up:
How can I have multiple computers with the `--increment` option enabled work and avoid any duplicate checks?

Answer (score 1):

Because `-s` and `--increment` cannot be used together:

> Use of --skip/--limit is not supported with --increment or mask files.

... the usual way to manage this is to divide up the "mask space" yourself instead - breaking the mask down into multiple smaller masks that cover the same keyspace.

For example, you could:

- run ?a x8 on one system, and ?a x9 on another
- divide the masks into sub-masks, such as ?l?a?a?a?a?a?a?a, ?d?a?a?a?a?a?a?a, ?s?a?a?a?a?a?a?a and ?u?a?a?a?a?a?a?a, and run each on separate systems

Note that you can also put a list of masks into a file, so you could use one *set* of masks on each system.

This manual division of work is OK for one-off cracking jobs, but if you need to do this on a regular basis, you can use something like [Hashtopolis](https://github.com/hashtopolis/server), which divides work up automatically depending on the capability of each client, including subdividing the masks for you.

Comment: Hashtopolis works great. It hasn't let me down once